# How to use batch script with xmgrace

Tags: plot, xmgrace

I am trying to use a batch script to plot data with xmgrace. However, I have encountered major problems in trying to find documentation on how to do this. I am trying to produce a panel plot, with graphs looking like this:

[image]

I am having problems with three things in doing so:

1) I want to be able to specify the limits of the x- and y-axis for each graph in the panel plot (or even better for all graphs at the same time) and I haven't found how to do this.

2) The data is stored in six columns in two different files. The x-values are in column 1 for both files. I would like to be able to import the data with a similar syntax as in gnuplot where I'd use

> plot 'file.dat' using 1:(2.0*$3)

to plot column 3 against column 1, and multiply the values in column 3 by 2.0. The important thing here is that I need to multiply some of the columns in one of the files with 2.0 to compare them with the content of the other file in a comprehensible way. I would also prefer a syntax where I can import the columns one at a time, instead of using

> READ NXY "file.dat"

where it reads all columns and I have to KILL the ones I don't want.

3) How do I change the dimensions of the graph? Changing the dimensions of the canvas using

> PAGE SIZE width, height

doesn't change the dimensions of the graph, or it does but not to fill the canvas. The default size for a panel plot with 4 by 2 graphs (which is what I want) does not show enough detail.

I have found this page to be somewhat helpful:
http://ringo.ams.sunysb.edu/index.php/Xmgrace

but it does not contain examples of everything I need to do.

So far, my batch script looks like:

> # make a panel plot
>    arrange (1,1,.1,.2,.5,ON,OFF,OFF)
>    # chose the first panel
>    FOCUS G0
>    # I was hoping this line would allow me to change the axis limits, but it isn't working:
>    world 0, -1, 20, 1
>    #each file has 6 columns
>    #s0 to s4
>    READ NXY "file2.dat"
>    #s5 to s9
>    READ NXY "file1.dat"
>        s0 line color 1
>        s1 line color 2
>        s2 line color 3
>        s3 line color 4
>        #s5 and s6 need to be multiplied by 2.0
>        s5 line color 1
>        s5 linestyle 4
>        s6 line color 2
>        s6 linestyle 4
>        s7 line color 3
>        s7 linestyle 4
>        s8 line color 4
>        s8 linestyle 4
>        s9 line color 5
>        KILL G0.s4
>        xaxis label "time"
>        xaxis tick place normal
>        yaxis label "density"
>    PAGE SIZE 2500, 2000

Answer (score 3):

1)  To specify the limits of the x- and y-axis for all graphs at the same time, use the following commands.

```
WORLD XMIN 0
WORLD XMAX 20
WORLD YMIN -2
WORLD YMAX 2
```

and optionally specify the ticks (major and minor) along x-axis as

```
XAXIS TICK MAJOR 0.5
XAXIS TICK MINOR 0.25
```

2)  The syntax to import the columns one at a time is

```
READ BLOCK "file2.dat"
BLOCK xy "1:2"
BLOCK xy "1:3"
BLOCK xy "1:4"
BLOCK xy "1:5"
READ BLOCK "file2.dat"
BLOCK xy "1:2"
BLOCK xy "1:3"
BLOCK xy "1:4"
BLOCK xy "1:5"
BLOCK xy "1:6"
```

To perform algebraic operations with specific columns, such as multiplying `columns 2` and `3` of `"file.dat"` with `2`, you can use

```
s4.y = 2*s4.y
s5.y = 2*s5.y
```

Note that as additional blocks of data are read in, newer sets with incremental suffixes are created, such as `s0, s1, s2, ....`. Since `column 6` of `file2.dat` is not read, the sets are numbered differently here relative to the original script.

3) To change dimensions of a graph (say `G0`)

```
FOCUS G0;
VIEW 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.85
```