# Customization of the plot appearence in XMGRACE

Tags: bash, plot, xmgrace

I create png graphs using xmgrace via the bash script working from the terminal w/o gui:

```
gracebat *.xvg -hdevice PNG -fixed 400 260 -printfile *.png -hardcopy
```

could you suggest me commands (or alternatively a script for the batch mode) which will customize the output graphs? In particular, I would like to increase the size and the font along the XY axes and customize the legend.

If xmgrace is not a good editor, could you suggest me another command-line utility for linux with better options for the graphs visualization?

Thank you!

Comment: Batch scripts in xmgrace have been covered before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41068223

Answer (score 0):

In addition to grace batch files, you have a few more (non mutually exclusive) options:

- You can use a custom Default.agr (see [here](http://lptms.u-psud.fr/wiki/index.php/Tips_for_Xmgrace#Creating_a_default_template_graph_used_when_opening_xmgrace) for an example) to improve the visual appearance of your plots out-of-the-box
- You can use parameter files: create a plot (with legend and all) and use the "Load -> Save parameters..." menu option to save a parameter file. From bash, use the `-param` switch to use that parameter file with other sets of data (*e.g.* `gracebat *.xvg -param myparams.par -hdevice PNG -fixed 400 260 -printfile *.png -hardcopy`).
- You can use (or write) a utility program to automatically edit .agr files (which are plain text files). A really nice one is [pygrace](http://pygrace.github.io/). With pygrace you can easily write python scripts that generate or edit agr files in a very straightforward way.